# Language files in java

Tags: java, yaml, translation, multilingual

I am making java application and I wanna to make her multilingual. Inside of app is over one thousand messages to translate, and I made simple system to load messages from file. I have problem with creating translates file, because I wanna to make hints for translators like description and parmas(placeholders) used in specifed message, for make that work easier, but in my way that looks that(Now i am using YAML files):

```
hello:
 COMMENT:
   description: Message executed on player join to session
   params:
     '1': USER_NAME
     '2': SESSION_NAME
 translation: Hello $1! (session: $2)
```

which is pretty ugly especially with yaml highlighting, and I wanna to change that to something like:

```
# Params:
#   1 = USER_NAME
#   2 = SESSION_NAME
# Message executed on player join to session
hello: Hello $1! (session: $2)
```

Is there way to add 'stack' of comment over specified key in yaml? Or exists other type of files with java support which allow me to do that and also will be able me to get List of Strings like in yaml from one key?

Comment: The standard way to do this in Java is with resource bundles, putting the text in `*.properties` files. See [Internationalization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Comment: Use a standard format, maybe based on XML: **xliff** (or **tmx**) and generate YAML or such from that. This allows a better automation by translation agencies besides those comments. The extra step plays no role, as versioning must be done too per language.

Comment: I saw that but, one problem is in .properties files for me that to save multiple comments from my java language file to properties file + I wanna to list of Strings in text file looks like in yaml which every one are starting in new line, and are not separeted by special character or something

Comment: Your second code listing is valid YAML and seems to do exactly what you expect. What is your problem?

Comment: Problem is in "How to generate that from code?"

Comment: Your question did not state that you autogenerate YAML with code. You can probably not use a YAML emitter because few can generate and format comments (as they are a presentation detail and therefore generally available as part of the API). You may be better off with properties.